# Find each employee Project Start Date and End Date (i.e., Start Date and End Date should be continuous without any break in Days/Months/Year)

Tags: sql-server, date, datetime

| ID | EmployeeId | ProjectId | StartDate | EndDate |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 100 | 01-04-2019 | 30-04-2019 |
| 2 | 1 | 100 | 01-05-2019 | 31-05-2019 |
| 3 | 1 | 100 | 01-12-2019 | 31-12-2019 |
| 4 | 1 | 100 | 01-01-2020 | 31-01-2020 |
| 5 | 2 | 200 | 01-01-2019 | 31-01-2019 |
| 6 | 2 | 200 | 01-02-2019 | 28-02-2019 |
| 7 | 2 | 200 | 01-04-2019 | 28-04-2019 |
| 8 | 2 | 200 | 01-05-2019 | 31-05-2019 |
| 9 | 2 | 200 | 01-06-2019 | 30-06-2019 |
| 10 | 3 | 100 | 01-08-2019 | 31-08-2019 |
| 11 | 3 | 100 | 01-09-2019 | 30-09-2019 |
| 12 | 3 | 200 | 01-10-2019 | 31-10-2019 |
| 13 | 3 | 200 | 01-11-2019 | 30-11-2019 |
| 14 | 3 | 300 | 01-12-2019 | 31-12-2019 |
| 15 | 3 | 300 | 01-01-2020 | 31-01-2020 |
| 16 | 3 | 300 | 01-02-2020 | 29-02-2020 |

expected Output

| EmployeeId | ProjectId | StartDate | EndDate |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 100 | 01-04-2019 | 31-05-2019 |
| 1 | 100 | 01-12-2019 | 31-01-2020 |
| 2 | 200 | 01-01-2019 | 28-02-2019 |
| 2 | 200 | 01-04-2019 | 28-04-2019 |
| 2 | 200 | 01-05-2019 | 30-06-2019 |
| 3 | 100 | 01-08-2019 | 30-09-2019 |
| 3 | 200 | 01-10-2019 | 30-11-2019 |
| 3 | 300 | 01-12-2019 | 29-02-2020 |

I have tried to find the enddate of the currentrow is enddate+1 is startdate of the next row,if it is continious without any gaps then need to select startdate of the previous row and enddate of current row.

```sql
;with MyCTE as

(

select mt.EmployeeId, mt.StartDate, mt.EndDate, ROW_NUMBER() over (order by ID) as RowNum

from #Employees mt

)

select c1.employeeId, case when c2.employeeId is null then c1.StartDate else dateadd(dd,1, c2.EndDate) end as StartDate,

c1.EndDate

from MyCTE c1
left  join MyCTE c2 
on C1.employeeId=c2.employeeId and
--and dateadd(dd,1,c1.startdate) 
c1.RowNum = c2.RowNum +1
```

Comment: This sounds like a very typical gaps and islands problem. There are hundreds of examples of this type of query all over stack overflow, and probably thousands all over the internet.

Comment: Here is a particularly good article which groups contiguous dates just like you are trying to do here. https://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/group-islands-of-contiguous-dates-sql-spackle

Answer (score 0):

**This is a classic gaps-and-islands problem.**

There are many solutions. A typical simple (if not very efficient) solution, is as follows:

- Use `LAG` to identify rows which start a group/island (partitioning as necessary)
- Use a windowed `COUNT` to assign a group ID to each of those
- Group by that ID, and take the `MIN`/`MAX` of the values

```sql
WITH PrevValues AS (
    SELECT *,
      IsStart = CASE WHEN DATEADD(day, -1, StartDate) <=
                  LAG(EndDate) OVER (PARTITION BY EmployeeId, ProjectId ORDER BY StartDate)
                THEN NULL ELSE 1 END
    FROM Employees e
),
Groups AS (
    SELECT *,
      GroupId = COUNT(IsStart) OVER (PARTITION BY EmployeeId, ProjectId ORDER BY StartDate ROWS UNBOUNDED PRECEDING)
    FROM PrevValues pv
)
SELECT
  g.EmployeeId,
  g.ProjectId,
  StartDate = MIN(StartDate),
  EndDate = MAX(EndDate)
FROM Groups g
GROUP BY
  g.EmployeeId,
  g.ProjectId,
  g.GroupId;
```

[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=d9189ec37eeb7718a296f58a176634e3)